# How the string "Hello" is placed in memory

Tags: mips

I'm new in mips and i have read some about Big endian and little endian.
I'm wondering how the string "Hello" is placed in memory in mips processor?

Comment: What do you think it looks like little endian and what do you think it looks like big endian and which do you thing mips uses?

Comment: That string is a sequence of characters (bytes in ASCII), and the characters will be placed in memory in the same order regardless of endianness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big endian the most significant byte is placed on the lowest memory address, and least significant byte is placed on the highest memory address.

The little endian is just the opposite.

"Hello" is 6 bytes including the null, here is the the "Hello" in hex `0x48 65 6C 6C 6F 21 00` and it's organized in so since every two character is one byte so it will be placed in memory in with the  the most significant byte also `0x48` in the lowest memory address in MIPS.

Comment: ASCII strings are stored as an array of single bytes, so little-endian would also have them in `0x48 65 6C 6C 6F 21 00` order.  Endianness has no effect because there are no multi-byte word values here.